# Why can't std::function bind to C-style variadic functions?

Tags: c++, c++11

For example, this fails to compile:

`std::function<decltype(printf)> my_printf(printf);`

With gcc, the error message reads:

```
error: variable 'std::function<int(const char*, ...)> my_printf' has initializer but incomplete type
     std::function<decltype(printf)> my_printf(printf);
```

At first I thought this was a bug in gcc, but then I looked at the standard and it looks like this just isn't supported. What's the technical reason for this?

Comment: I could write a class equivalent to `std::function` in C++11: as it is, `std::function` can be written as a pure header file class in a standard conforming way.  I am uncertain if I could write `std::function< int(const char*, ...) >` without extending the language or using compiler specific extensions.  Can we have `virtual` C-style variardic methods?  And even if so, the internal type erasure object would then have to forward `...` arguments to `printf`, which is not supported AFAIK.

Comment: @Yakk:  FYI, you can have a `virtual` C style varadic method.  The issue is that there is no way to pass the C-style varadic parameters to another function without converting to a va_list or parsing them yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is one of implementation.  Let's say it was possible.  Then `std::function` would have to declare (in the case of printf)

`int operator()(char* fmt, ...)`

When called, it would then have to pass the contents of ... to whatever object you assigned.  The issue is that it doesn't know enough about the arguments to know HOW to pass that down, which is an issue.  printf() parses the format, but others use other mechanisms (an 'end' value is popular).

For the printf family of functions, I suggest you look at the vXXX versions (e.g. vprintf).  Since they use well defined arguments (the last one being the variable argument list), it would be possible to bind `std::function` to those versions.

Edit:

What you can do, however, is write your own wrapper that uses the `vprintf` functions, and handles the vararg-> va_list conversion.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <functional>

class PrintWrapper
{

    public:
    PrintWrapper()  = default;


    template<typename T>
    PrintWrapper( T&& t)  : func(std::forward<T>(t))
    {

    }


    int operator()(char const* format, ...)
    {
        va_list args;
        va_start(args, format);
        int result = func(format, args);
        va_end(args);
        return result;
    }
    private:

    std::function< int(char const*, va_list)> func;

};

int main()
{
    // Note, you have to use the 'v' versions
    PrintWrapper p = std::vprintf;
    p("%d %d %s\n", 1,2, "hello");
    char buffer[256];
    using namespace std::placeholders;
    p = std::bind(std::vsnprintf, buffer, sizeof(buffer), _1, _2 );

    p("%lf %s\n", 0.1234, "goodbye");

    // Since the previous step was a wrapper around snprintf, we need to print
    // the buffer it wrote into
    printf("%s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/Sc95ch

Comment: Actually, the `operator()` in `std::function` isn't the problem -- it could just use perfect forwarding.  The tricky part would be making the internal type erasure object work...

Comment: The key is that at some point in the implementation, you have to go from perfect forwarding to calling the type erasure mechanism, which cannot know what the arguments are at the call site, and that's where it fails.

Comment: I'd be tempted to do a C++11 style variardic signature on my `PrintWrapper`, then have it internally bounce to a C-style `...` variardic list, which it then does the `va_list` work in.  Simply to hide that `...` as far away from the end user as reasonable...

Comment: @Yakk: I would support the motion especially in light of the fact that C++ users often accidentally pass erroneous arguments to `printf` (class object, ...); however if you go there, just write a variadic template implementation of `printf` and be done with it ;)

Comment: @MatthieuM.  Oddly enough, I've [got the start of one of those too](https://ideone.com/EXDgyT).  It doesn't do any correctness checking on the pattern, just passes through to standard printf, but it does convert objects to strings, and all strings (as a second step) to `const char*` before passing it along, which is a step up.

Answer (score 0):

Write your own template class.

```
template<typename F>
struct function2
{
    F f;

    template<typename... Args>
    decltype(auto) operator()(Args&&... a)
    {
        return f(a...);
    }
};


function2 a{ printf };
a("%d %u %x %p %s", 1, 1, 1, &a, "test");
```