# how to construct class whose constructor function might have multiple parameter or none in template?

Tags: templates, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

Now I want to write a general template which can instance class, of course, these classes might have none or multiple parameters. So the template must have variadic arguments. Anybody can help me?

To better make myself understood, please see the follwong simple code snippet, I don't know how to make it work:

```
class Print
{
public:
    Print(const char* param, const char* param2)
        : m_str1(param)
        , m_str2(param2)
    {}
    void outPut()
    {
        std::cout << m_str1 << "\t" << m_str2 << std::endl;
    }
private:
    std::string m_str1;
    std::string m_str2;
};

template<typename ... Ts>
struct adapter
{
    static void invoke()
    {
        C t((Ts::value)...); // make a instance on the fly
    }
};
```

**update:**
When I try to write such code, it won't compile:

```
adapter<const char*, const char*>;
```

Comment: What problem are you seeing?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to create an arbitrary instance of the `Ts` types, but I suspect you want real values. If the `Ts` are `const char *`, what do you want the string values to be?  Having a more complete example of the problem (with a main) may make it more clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @VaughnCato, see this question I asked before, it contained the full context, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25580294/c-11stdintegral-constantchar-kernel32-dll-wont-compile

Comment: Are you looking for something like this? http://ideone.com/4l4ekb

Comment: @VaughnCato, 'constexpr' is not supported in VS 2013, thank you all the same

Comment: Ok, well that's not a big deal to work around: http://ideone.com/A0qdSW

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct adapter
{
    template<typename ... Ts>
    static T invoke(Ts&& ... ts)
    {
        return T(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...); // make a instance on the fly
    }
};
```

To create an object of type `T`, you would call `adapter<T>::invoke` with the appropriate arguments.

Comment: Fixed. You will also need to include the header `<utility>`.

Comment: one more quesion, what if I remove '&&'? it still can compile. what's the use of '&&'?

Comment: That makes use of C++11's reference collapsing rules allowing both rvalues and lvalues to bind to the functions parameters. `std::forward` ensures that this information is correctly forwarded to the next function.

Comment: if not use '&&', any bad effect?