# std::function with C variadic arguments, not templated variable arguments

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-functions, std-function

I basically want to do the following:

```
typedef
std::function<int(const char* format, ...)> PrintfLikeFunction;
```

However, that does not seem to work.

Is that possible? I really need to match functions with variadic arguments in my case so that I could pass in `printf`.

The other reason is, I want to have

```
void doSomething(PrintfLikeFunction logger);
```

and the implementation should be separate, thus this must not be a template function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't possible with `std::function`.

[It's pretty much impossible to forward C-style variadic arguments directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18370396/why-cant-stdfunction-bind-to-c-style-variadic-functions), without knowing what arguments were actually passed.

Depending on the circumstances, you might just take a function pointer - a `int(*)(const char*, ...)`, or, if type erasure is necessary, rework your code to use the variant taking a `va_list`.